# ActionBarSherlock library not recognizing

Tags: android, eclipse, actionbarsherlock

I imported android project from idea to eclipse and I have a problem: ActionBarSherlock, MediaLibrary etc. are not recognized.In project properties I see a such thing [image]

and in library tree the situation is:

[image]

root element is my main project. How to make this actionbarsherlock and the others recognizable?

Comment: Remove lib with remove, and then add same lib.
Android Developer Tools do not use the name of a project to reference it, but instead point to the directory itself

Answer (score 0):

If your configuration has worked before, try to remove all libraries from your project, do a clean build (I don't know if this is necessary, but just to be sure). Then open your project-properties again and add your libraries to the project. Now check after you clicked ok and the project has rebuild, if your libraries are now recognized.

Comment: in Project->Properties->Java build path->Libraries I have onle android.jar, you mean remove and add it?

Comment: no from the screen where you have taken the screenshot off remove all libraries marked with a red cross. Click ok. Clear all projects, add the libraries again.

Comment: I did that and then after removing I pressed add button and the selection dialog is empty

Comment: ABS, PullToRefresh must be library. In the same screen, for each single project you have to flag "Is Library"

Comment: then check the properties of your library and take a look if the checkbox "is library" has been checked

Answer (score 0):

are the projects located on different drives?
i had the same issue and then noticed that if you look at the android project file, you'll notice that the location of those libraries is set as relative.
in eclipse, there's a difference between the location of the actual code and the data in the workspace. you need to pay attention to that difference.

i moved the sources of the ABS (action bar sherlock) and the sources of my android project to the same disk - logical or physical, and re-selected the reference to the ABS project.
this worked and solved the problem for me.